# How to pause video when other app play music and resume once the music stops?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

When the video is playing and I resume the music from notification in the Music app, the video is still playing. Both music and video are playing concurrently. What I want is to pause the video when the music is started. Youtube app does what I am explaining here. When googled, I found that AudioFocus is used for MediaPlayer in such cases. Does VideoView support AudioFocus if yes then how to use that to achieve above goal?

Comment: Have you tried to pause your MediaPlayer/ExoPlayer when onPause is called?

Comment: I am using videoview and in this case onPaused is not called. I play video and swipe down status bar where there is a music app's service notification to play music.

Comment: I might be wrong but you can try using Broadcast receiver, so when it detects music starting to play, video is stopped, because it gets notification from Broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `changeAudioFocus(true);`

when you start playing media from your app. It will create an `OnAudioFocusChangeListener` and set it with `AudioManager`, and you will get a callback when you get `AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS` or `AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT` message.

You also get `AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK`, which is used to lower the volume of the player, which some media players do when you get a notification sound.

```
/**
  * Used to indicate a transient loss of audio focus where the loser of the audio focus can
     * lower its output volume if it wants to continue playing (also referred to as "ducking"), as
     * the new focus owner doesn't require others to be silent.
     * @see OnAudioFocusChangeListener#onAudioFocusChange(int)
     */
```

code

```
    private final OnAudioFocusChangeListener mAudioFocusListener = createOnAudioFocusChangeListener();
    private AudioManager mAudioManager = null;
    private boolean mHasAudioFocus = false;
    private void changeAudioFocus(boolean acquire) {
        if (mAudioManager == null)
            mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (mAudioManager == null)
            return;

        if (acquire) {
            if (!mHasAudioFocus) {
                final int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mAudioFocusListener,
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
                if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                    mAudioManager.setParameters("bgm_state=true");
                    mHasAudioFocus = true;
                }
            }
        } else if (mHasAudioFocus) {
            mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mAudioFocusListener);
            mAudioManager.setParameters("bgm_state=false");
            mHasAudioFocus = false;
        }
    }

private OnAudioFocusChangeListener createOnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    return new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        int audioDuckLevel = -1;
        private int mLossTransientVolume = -1;
        private boolean wasPlaying = false;

        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
            /*
             * Pause playback during alerts and notifications
             */
            switch (focusChange) {
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS");
                    // Pause playback
                    changeAudioFocus(false);
                    pause();
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");
                    // Pause playback
                    pausePlayback();
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN: ");
                    // Resume playback
                    if (mLossTransientVolume != -1) {
                            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mLossTransientVolume, 0);
                        mLossTransientVolume = -1;
                    }
                    if (mLossTransient) {
                        if (wasPlaying && mSettings.getBoolean("resume_playback", true))
                            play();
                        mLossTransient = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void pausePlayback() {
            if (mLossTransient) return;
            mLossTransient = true;
            wasPlaying = isPlaying();
            if (wasPlaying) pause();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: tried this but didn't work so I did a dirty work around. I used _onWindowFocusChanged()_which is called when status bar is slide down and check if mediaPlayer is playing or not inside this function. This only works for my app's music.

Comment: should have worked, using same code in this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mn2square.slowmotionplayer
and is working fine.